# Cannot connect to MongoDB on AWS (errno:111 Connection refused)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, connection, database-connection

I have followed AWS' instructions ([link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest/doc/MongoDB_on_the_AWS_Cloud.pdf)) for installing MongoDB on AWS, and things seem to work until I try to connect to it.

When I run `mongo`, I get this connection error:

```
2015-07-21T23:07:01.188+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-07-21T23:07:01.188+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
```

And that happens even if I comment out the `bind_ip` setting in the **mongod.conf** file (a common suggestion on forums), or set it to 0.0.0.0. Mongo did install, as I can run `mongo --nodb` successfully. Can someone suggest help with my connection problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Whoops, my script had not the permissions needed to start the mongo daemon, so I started it manually with `sudo service mongod start`, and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Is the `mongod` running. Try `ps -ax | grep mongod`

Comment: That was the issue, thanks @Sundar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"mongo --nodb"** will start a "dummy mongod service" and connect you directly into to it.

**"mongo"** will try to find a mongod service on port 27017 (standard port) on 127.0.0.1 (standard host).  Equals: *mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017*

To check if your mongod service has started on your server:

```
$ ps -aux | grep mongo        #check if service runs
$ netstat -nap | grep 27017   #check if port is 27017
```

Start your mongod service:

```
$ sudo service mongod start
```

If still not working, check your logfile:

```
$ tail -n100 /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```